# How can I route/reference one to one relationship in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry, I am very new to Ruby on Rails, a bit confused on how to route tables with one to one ralationshipts

I have two models, User and Userdetail

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :userdetail
end

class Userdetail< ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

In my application.html.erb I am trying to add a link for a user to go to user details, something like that

```
<%= link_to 'User Information', userdetail_path %>
```

How can I make this link to work, what should I place in my routes.rb file to reference one to one relationshipt of User and Userdetail

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to reference the one-to-one relationship to get a `userdetail_path` helper. In your `routes.rb`, make sure you have this:

```rb
resource :userdetail, only: :show
```